# Code Wont Build On Different Machine With Same OS And Compiler

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost, conan

I cant seem to find much on this error. I have a C++ code-base, I hand off to my professor, it has a build script that installs conan then dependencies from conan. I originally wrote the codebase on Windows but it worked fine on `ubuntu:latest` CI on github. It also works fine in a `ubuntu:latest` docker container on my local machine that I ported it over too. My local docker container says it is `ubuntu 20.04`. My professor has both a `ubuntu 20.04` and an `ubuntu 20.10`, both get the same error, here is they're build log

```
$ cmake --version                                                        
cmake version 3.16.3
9:03
$ gcc --version                                                          
gcc (Ubuntu 10.2.0-13ubuntu1) 10.2.0
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
9:03
$ conan --version                                                        
Conan version 1.33.1
9:04
$ ./build.sh                                                              
Configuration:
[settings]
arch=x86_64
arch_build=x86_64
build_type=Release
compiler=gcc
compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11
compiler.version=10
os=Linux
os_build=Linux
[options]
[build_requires]
[env]conanfile.txt: Installing package
Requirements
   boost/1.75.0 from 'conan-center' - Cache
   bzip2/1.0.8 from 'conan-center' - Cache
   catch2/2.13.4 from 'conan-center' - Cache
   libiconv/1.16 from 'conan-center' - Cache
   nlohmann_json/3.9.1 from 'conan-center' - Cache
   openssl/1.1.1i from 'conan-center' - Cache
   zlib/1.2.11 from 'conan-center' - Cache
Packages
   boost/1.75.0:91068d6d6067a809e746602e9538e15eddb14457 - Cache
   bzip2/1.0.8:91a8b22c2c5a149bc617cfc06cdd21bf23b12567 - Cache
   catch2/2.13.4:5ab84d6acfe1f23c4fae0ab88f26e3a396351ac9 - Cache
   libiconv/1.16:19729b9559f3ae196cad45cb2b97468ccb75dcd1 - Cache
   nlohmann_json/3.9.1:d1091b2ed420e6d287293709a907ae824d5de508 - Cache
   openssl/1.1.1i:19729b9559f3ae196cad45cb2b97468ccb75dcd1 - Cache
   zlib/1.2.11:19729b9559f3ae196cad45cb2b97468ccb75dcd1 - CacheInstalling (downloading, building) binaries...
bzip2/1.0.8: Already installed!
catch2/2.13.4: Already installed!
libiconv/1.16: Already installed!
libiconv/1.16: Appending PATH environment var: .conan/data/libiconv/1.16/_/_/package/19729b95
59f3ae196cad45cb2b97468ccb75dcd1/bin                                                                         
nlohmann_json/3.9.1: Already installed!
openssl/1.1.1i: Already installed!
zlib/1.2.11: Already installed!
boost/1.75.0: Already installed!
boost/1.75.0: WARN: Picked up a system libbacktrace library
conanfile.txt: Generator txt created conanbuildinfo.txt
conanfile.txt: Generator cmake created conanbuildinfo.cmake
conanfile.txt: Generated conaninfo.txt
conanfile.txt: Generated graphinfo
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 10.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 10.2.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Conan: Adjusting output directories
-- Conan: Using cmake global configuration
-- Conan: Adjusting default RPATHs Conan policies
-- Conan: Adjusting language standard
-- Current conanbuildinfo.cmake directory: workspace/Spring2021/Capstone/Project1Grading/project/build
-- Conan: Compiler GCC>=5, checking major version 10
-- Conan: Checking correct version: 10
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: workspace/Spring2021/Capstone/Project1Grading/project/build
make[1]: Entering directory 'workspace/Spring2021/Capstone/Project1Grading/project/build'
make[2]: Entering directory 'workspace/Spring2021/Capstone/Project1Grading/project/build'
Scanning dependencies of target tests
make[2]: Leaving directory 'workspace/Spring2021/Capstone/Project1Grading/project/build'
make[2]: Entering directory 'workspace/Spring2021/Capstone/Project1Grading/project/build'
[ 14%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/tests.dir/Source/Connect.cpp.o
In file included from .conan/data/boost/1.75.0/_/_/package/91068d6d6067a809e746602e9538e15edd
b14457/include/boost/asio/ssl/rfc2818_verification.hpp:26,
                from .conan/data/boost/1.75.0/_/_/package/91068d6d6067a809e746602e9538e15edd
b14457/include/boost/asio/ssl.hpp:21,
                from workspace/Spring2021/Capstone/Project1Grading/project
/Source/LoadRootCertificate.hpp:13,
                from workspace/Spring2021/Capstone/Project1Grading/project
/Source/Connect.hpp:26,
                from workspace/Spring2021/Capstone/Project1Grading/project
/Source/Connect.cpp:16:
.conan/data/boost/1.75.0/_/_/package/91068d6d6067a809e746602e9538e15eddb14457/include/boost/a
sio/detail/push_options.hpp:82:12: error: ‘#pragma’ is not allowed here
  82 | #  pragma GCC visibility push (default)
     |           ^~~
In file included from .conan/data/boost/1.75.0/_/_/package/91068d6d6067a809e746602e9538e15edd
b14457/include/boost/asio/ssl/rfc2818_verification.hpp:92,
                from .conan/data/boost/1.75.0/_/_/package/91068d6d6067a809e746602e9538e15edd
b14457/include/boost/asio/ssl.hpp:21,
                from workspace/Spring2021/Capstone/Project1Grading/project
/Source/LoadRootCertificate.hpp:13,
                from workspace/Spring2021/Capstone/Project1Grading/project
/Source/Connect.hpp:26,
                from workspace/Spring2021/Capstone/Project1Grading/project
/Source/Connect.cpp:16:
.conan/data/boost/1.75.0/_/_/package/91068d6d6067a809e746602e9538e15eddb14457/include/boost/a
sio/detail/pop_options.hpp:74:27: warning: no matching push for ‘#pragma GCC visibility pop’ [-Wpragmas]
  74 | #  pragma GCC visibility pop
     |                          ^~~
In file included from .conan/data/boost/1.75.0/_/_/package/91068d6d6067a809e746602e9538e15edd
b14457/include/boost/asio/ssl/rfc2818_verification.hpp:95,
                from .conan/data/boost/1.75.0/_/_/package/91068d6d6067a809e746602e9538e15edd
b14457/include/boost/asio/ssl.hpp:21,
                from workspace/Spring2021/Capstone/Project1Grading/project
/Source/LoadRootCertificate.hpp:13,
                from workspace/Spring2021/Capstone/Project1Grading/project
/Source/Connect.hpp:26,
                from workspace/Spring2021/Capstone/Project1Grading/project
/Source/Connect.cpp:16:
.conan/data/boost/1.75.0/_/_/package/91068d6d6067a809e746602e9538e15eddb14457/include/boost/a
sio/ssl/impl/rfc2818_verification.ipp:34:6: error: ‘rfc2818_verification’ has not been declared
  34 | bool rfc2818_verification::operator()(
     |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
.conan/data/boost/1.75.0/_/_/package/91068d6d6067a809e746602e9538e15eddb14457/include/boost/a
sio/ssl/impl/rfc2818_verification.ipp:35:44: error: non-member function ‘bool boost::asio::ssl::operator()(bo
ol, boost::asio::ssl::verify_context&)’ cannot have cv-qualifier
  35 |    bool preverified, verify_context& ctx) const
     |                                           ^~~~~
.conan/data/boost/1.75.0/_/_/package/91068d6d6067a809e746602e9538e15eddb14457/include/boost/a
sio/ssl/impl/rfc2818_verification.ipp:34:6: error: ‘bool boost::asio::ssl::operator()(bool, boost::asio::ssl:
:verify_context&)’ must be a nonstatic member function
  34 | bool rfc2818_verification::operator()(
     |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
.conan/data/boost/1.75.0/_/_/package/91068d6d6067a809e746602e9538e15eddb14457/include/boost/a
sio/ssl/impl/rfc2818_verification.ipp:126:6: error: ‘rfc2818_verification’ has not been declared
 126 | bool rfc2818_verification::match_pattern(const char* pattern,
     |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I did discover that I was using `gcc 9.3.0` while they were using `gcc 10.2.0`, so I updated, changing the conan profile, deleting build files, reinstalling deps on the container and everything, and it still built.

As you can see, it errors out with `error: ‘#pragma’ is not allowed` within a `boost::asio` header file. I'm really not sure what the problem is both github and local docker build fine with the same version of Ubuntu. GCC, cmake, & conan are the same too. I'm really confused. I do know some of the deps use glibc and some use newlib, from what he tells me it seems they did update their conan profile, could there be an issue there somewhere? Could it be something wrong with they're GCC install? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Out on a limb, it may be you're including a boost header at a point where you cannot syntactically do that, e.g.:

```
struct X {
    int a, b, c;
    void foo() {
        /* lot's of code
        */

    }


 // OOPS forgot closing }; for the struct
 #include <boost/optional.hpp>
```

The include there would cause those errors.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately I don't have this class anymore so I cant ask him to test it, and I probably kinda blew away the repo or something.

Comment: Feel free to delete this question because it won't be of any assistance to anyone else in the future.